# Robotframework - how to fix this deprecated functionality ${row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')}

Tags: selenium, robotframework

At somepoint there was an update to some functionality and now the following doesnt work on robotframework anymore
${row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')}

I cant seem to fix this and cant find much support

I believe the new way is done by using by.TAG_NAME() or something like that

For context im getting the table rows (tr) and storing it in a list, for each tr I want to get the table divisions (td) so I can create a list of each tr but have access to the td within.
This is done so I can check a csv file matches the table when exported
Below is the section of code

```
@{severity_list}=   Create List

    FOR  ${page}  IN RANGE  99999
        @{rows}=    Get Alarms Table Rows
        FOR  ${row}  IN  @{rows}
            @{elements}=  Set Variable   ${row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')}
            # Train Severity List
            @{train_severity}=  Create List  
            Append To List  ${train_severity}  ${elements[2].text}
            Append To List  ${train_severity}  ${elements[3].text}
            # Get Severity value
            Append To List  ${severity_list}    ${train_severity}
        END
```

I believe the new way is done by using by.TAG_NAME() or something like that

```
ERROR Message:Resolving variable '${row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')}' failed: 
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Is it throwing an error, and if so, what is the error?

Comment: Hello @BryanOakley the error is below, i think it doesnt work because the functionality has been deprecated/changed with a new release of selenium
Resolving variable '${row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')}' failed: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the error message there.